# How to have a function accept all types of arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, function

I'm kinda new to Swift and I was wondering how do I make a function accept an array that contains all kinds of variables types. I want the function to just accept 'Array' without a specific type but it throws an error. Here's my code:

```
func length(arry arry: Array)
{

}
```

I know I have to put a <> after the Array but I need the function to universally accept all arrays.

**EDITED:**
Whenever I add an extension I get these ridiculous errors. My code is:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
extension Array {
var length: Int {
    return self.count
}
}
var arrY = ["Hello", 0]

for(var i = 0; i < length(arry: arrY); i++)
{
print(arrY[i]);
}

arrY.append(28);
var h = arrY.removeAtIndex(0);
print(h);
```

I get errors saying:
  1 On line ten Extensions may not contain stored properties
  2 On line eleven Expected Declaration
  3 On line eighteen Expected Declaration
Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Use generic function

Comment: Why not just use the built in `count` property?

Comment: Because I'm very used to Java and other languages like that so I am used to using .length and I think length() is easier for me to remember than .count .

Comment: There's a typo in your version of my extension. You forgot to close the extension, a `}` is missing...

Comment: You're not using my extension as intended. Have a look at this [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOyzoDBNT8tFyYgAl4-TTFLDiBeS7Gzx2BU).

Comment: I know, that's why I wanted to use a function. Because I'm not always going to know what EXACTLY is in my array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want, you can write a generic function:

```
func length<T>(arry arry: Array<T>)
{

}
```

In Swift, Apple introduced the concept of `Generics` which you can also now find it on Xcode 7 and Objective-C. This feature allows you to define the type of each element in the Array or the collection class that you're using. You can define a generic class or a generic method like the sample given. This feature gives you the ability of writing your code in a way that it can work safely with different types, while taking advantage of being type-safe. For example, in the sample that I gave, it's saying that `length` is a generic method which takes an Array of type `T` as input. Writing a method like this, allows you to write one method which is capable of accepting arrays of different types. For example, following sample code, is showing that you can use the same method for both array of `Int` and array of `Double`:

```
var arr = [13, 23, 32]
var arr2 = [12.3, 23.5, 13.14, 2.75]
var arr3 = ["foo", "boo"]
length(arr)
length(arr)
length(arr)
```

For more information on Generics you can check online documents at [this Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html), and/or watch Swift introduction videos for [WWDC 2014](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2014/), and/or reading generic section of [The Swift Programming Language](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11)

Comment: Your code worked. I looked at the link and I'm a little confused. Think you can explain your code?

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic function is the better answer. But you could also use `[Any]` as a parameter for this function.

```
func length(array: [Any])->Int{
    return array.count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're used to `.length` then make an extension to Array with a `length` property:

```
extension Array {
    var length: Int {
        return self.count
    }
}
```

Then you can call it on arrays like you're used to:

```
["a", "b"].length  // 2
[0, 1].length  // 2
```

Comment: It just sends an error when I try to use it with a array variable: 'Extensions may not store contained variables.'

Comment: I'm using this kind of extension all the time without problems. And I've tested this one before posting my answer, no problems whatsoever either. If you have an error, please explain how you get there.

Comment: Look at this [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOzlh-TeRMVGhqkiAktCDFhfYOkO0OiiAls) of my Playground when testing my answer (although I knew it would work I always test before posting).

Comment: Im saying when I do like: "var h = ["Hello", "Hello"] " then after "h.length"

Comment: There's a typo in your version. You forgot to close the extension, a `}` is missing...

Comment: Here's how your test should [look like](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOyzoDBNT8tFyYgAl4-TTFLDiBeS7Gzx2BU). It works, of course.